# nintex farm level workflow for Access request in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, access

I am looking for a nintex workflow that pulls / routes the access requests to a group which contains "Owner". The access request must reach the Owner group with reminders send twice from the day it was created. The request should get expired after 14 days of request creation. 1st reminder on 7th day, second reminder on 13th day. The user who places request should also get an email notification saying, these are the list of owners with whom the user's access request is pending approval.

Clients don't want us to touch Master page / SP designer. Hence they suggested through Nintex workflows. Is this possible ?

Note: this has to be implemented in a farm level